# Other proof that $h(x)=x^{p}\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $p\geq 1$. The function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by
\begin{align*}
    h(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        x^{p}   & \text{if } x\geq0\\
        0       & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
is convex. Is there a proof for this that does not consider cases then points are to the left and/or to the right of $0$? E.g. via the epigraph or operations that preserve convexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p>1$ a continuous derivative $h'$ exists and $h'$ is increasing This implies that $h$ is convex. The case $p=1$ is trivial.

[To prove that $h(tx+(1-t)y) \leq th(x)+(1-t)h(y)$ apply MVT to $h(y)-h(tx+(1-t)y)$ and $h(tx+(1-t)y)-h(x)$. You will see immediately  that $t(h(tx+(1-t)y)-h(x)) \leq (1-t) h(y)-h(tx+(1-t)y)$$ which is what we want to prove].